# urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

I am trying to connect to http://localhost:1438/~cs1xx/1x/007.php using `urllib2.urlopen`. But I get connection refused error. Can anyone help me out?

Below are the details and what I have tried so far:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 472, in <module>
    php_data = urllib2.urlopen(php_test)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

Here php_test is http://localhost:1438/~cs1xx/1x/007.php. I can access this site from my browser. I am also able to ping this using:

```
c$ nmap -p 1438 localhost

 Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-10-30 12:52 PDT
 Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
 Host is up (0.00016s latency).
 Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
 PORT     STATE  SERVICE
 1438/tcp closed eicon-server

 Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds
```

Edit:

Python code (only the relevant portion)

```
import os,sys
import urllib,urllib2;
php_test = submission_path + php_test_folder + test_file  # these are set somewhere
os.system("echo " + php_test)  # prints http://localhost:1438/~cs1xx/1x/007.php
php_data = urllib2.urlopen(php_test)
```

Comment: Can you post your python code?

Comment: Posted as edit.

Comment: instead of using nmap, which might mislead you, can you `curl` it or `wget` that url from the command line? connection refused may indicate a range of issues, not just that it can't connect, but that it can't establish a http protocol on that connection, where nmap -p I think only really shows that it can open the port.